# White cloud around fighter jet at Supersonic speed

Tags: speed

When a fighter jet flies with Supersonic speed then some type of white cloud form  around the fighter jet for short period of time.what is the reason behind this phenomena?

Comment: You're thinking of a [shock wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_wave) which momentarily condenses the air (due to the huge local pressure drop) which you're then able to see. You see a similar whitening of the air when bombs exploded (see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G5XdEwGyfEg) amazing video).